# Massive number of Estimated Rows compared to Actual

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014, sql-execution-plan

I've looked at many posts about this and can't figure out the issues. The stats are up to date, but the estimated number of rows is massively higher than the actual number.

Any suggestions where to look:

[image: Rows]

Comment: Were the statistics updated based on sampling or a fullscan?

Comment: Google DBCC Show_Statistics to answer Dan